# Accessing erpnext/frappe from the internet / Port-Fowarding?

Tags: linux, erpnext, frappe

recently i've installed erpnext/frappe with installation documentation. I've installed it on a linux cloud server (debian 11), succesfully. I've used the docker image, and then i started it. Everything seems to be find.

But then I don't know, how to access the install outside the vserver. the port is 8001, but calling IP-ADRESS:8001, an error (404 not found) shows up.

I am not sure how the correct term for this would be, i wanted to achieve, that the port 8001 (localhost:8001 seems working) is accessible from "outside".

Thanks

I've tried following commands:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i venet0 -p tcp --dport 8001 -j DNAT --to-destination 89.xxx.xxx.xx:8001
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 89.xxx.xxx.xxx--dport 8001 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -s 89.xxx.xxx.xxx-o venet0 -j MASQUERADE
```

where xxx are realy numbers... (filled with the ip i am trying to access)